# How do you prove this statement? If there exists a subset $Y$ of $X$ such that $Y\sim N$, then for any $x_0 \in X$, $(X-{x_o}) \sim X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you prove this statement in the set theory?

$X$ and $Y$ are sets. $X\sim Y$ means $X$ and $Y$ are equipotent, i.e. there is a bijection $f\colon X \to Y$. $x_o$ is a element of the set $X$.

If there exists a subset $Y$ of $X$ such that $Y\sim N$, then for any  $x_0 \in X$, $(X-{x_o}) \sim X$

Answer (score 0):

***Hints***:

- Try to prove that $\mathbb N - \{x_0\}\sim \mathbb N$
- Now try to prove $X - \{x_0\}\sim X$ when $x_0\in Y$
- solve the problem
- profit